# Windows 8 swipe gestures (synaptics no registry files)

Tags: windows-8, mouse, touchpad

I have an Asus s400c ultrabook and now some of its touchpad gestures like two fingers in metro UI, right egde and up edge swap wont work but rest of the gestures work pretty fine. I checked registry and there is no synaptics folder at all. Please help!

Comment: You need to install the Synaptic drivers for your device to work.

Comment: Synaptic thing wont work for my laptop because there is an asus gesture driver and I have already installed it

Comment: Why are you looking for registry keys connected to synaptics if you don't have it installed?  This sounds like a problem with the asus gesture drivers.

Comment: Ok so please any idea how to get those gestures back ? :(

Comment: Remove the asus gesture driver and use the Synaptic drivers instead.